# Application lagging at the time of scanning barcode

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, barcode-scanner

I created an application and the functionality of this app is when PASSENGER came to us for using our services we scanned their boarding pass (Barcode) and saved their information in our database to get monthly reports of how many passengers is using our services.
Okay so all of this is working very fine , Passenger came , we scanned and saved their information frequently but when there is a load of Passengers like 5 or 6 Passenger came to visit us together so than the app is hanging at the time of scanning and its stuck at that page.
Let me show you some code.
I have an View model with one Property that is string.
This is ActionMethod of scanning view

```
 public ActionResult Scaning(Scanning Request)
    {
        if (!General.ValidateSession())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
        }
        var Flights = FlightRepos.GetAllEmirates().Where(x=>x.isDelete==false);
        ViewBag.FlightNoList = Flights.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        { Text = x.FlightNo.ToString(), Value = x.ID.ToString() });

      //s  ViewBag.Passcategory = categoryrepos.GetAll().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name.ToString(), Value = x.ID.ToString() });
        ViewBag.Passcategory = categoryrepos.GetAll().Where(x=>x.ID!=4 && x.ID!=5).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.CategoryCode.ToString(), Value = x.ID.ToString() });
        var b = Request.Data.Split(' ');
        //   int c = b.Length;

        List<string> list = new List<string>(b);

        //  var list1 = new List<string>(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
            if (b[i].Equals(""))
            {
                list.Remove(b[i]);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

        b = list.ToArray();

        if (b.Length < 4)
        {
            return View("PleaseCheckManually");
        }
        var Model = new PassengerInfo(); 
        if (b[4].Length < 12 || b[4].Length > 12)
        {
            return View("PleaseCheckManually");
        }
        Model.Name = b[0];
        Model.SeatNo = b[4].Substring(4, 4);
        Model.SequenceNo = b[4].Substring(8);

        Model.FlightId = int.Parse(b[3]);
        if (Flights.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.FlightNo) == b[3]) == null)
        {
            Request = null;

            list = null;
            ViewData["flights"] = b[3];  
            ViewData["scan"] = "0";


            return View();
        }

        else
        {
            Model.FlightId = Flights.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.FlightNo) == b[3]).ID;

        }
        return View("CheckIn", Model);
    }
```

I have a view model which **Scanning** and through view I am taking the  **Barcode string** in it by scanning the boarding pass of PASSENGER.

**View**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Scaning";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<section id="contact-us-section" class="contact-us-section pb-30 image-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section contact-us">
            <div class="container">
                <br />
                <div class="slider-text-2 text-center pt-40">
                    <h2 class="font-w-8 font-30 ltr-s-1 pb-12 color-w" style="color:#e60053">Scan The Boarding Pass Of Passenger</h2>
                    <h4 class="color-w font-22"><a class="font-20 color-w" href="/Home/Index">Home</a></h4>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="outer-box">
                    <!-- Contact Form Start -->
                    <div class="form-box clearfix">
                        <div align="center">
                            <img src="~/Contents/images/Barcod.gif" style="width:50% ; height:auto" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 contact-us">
                            <form action="" method="post" id="scan-form">
                                <div class="styled-input">
                                    <input type="text" name="Data" placeholder="Name" required="" id="scanInput" hidden>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

That input name "Data" is my property name of the view model and when user scanned the boarding pass of the Passenger . The barcod string bind with this Data and through using Jquery i submitted the form and than I do some logical work on The method describe above.

This is the script for binding the barcode string and submitting the form.

```
<script>
var code = '';
var scanStarted = false;
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    code += e.key;
    if (!scanStarted) {
        scanStarted = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#scanInput').val(code);
            $('#scan-form').submit();
        }, 700);
    }
});
```

This is all working very fine when user came after the gap of 1 minute, but when a group of Passenger came than the app is lagging at the time of scanning .

Comment: There could be hundreds of reasons for this lag. You need to first identify where the lag is actually happening, client or server side, and go from there. I'd suggest using a request profiler on both client/server too.

Comment: it is on client side .. because the page is not directed on the next page, if you see my action method i am getting that barcode string and passing it on another view ..

Comment: You are calling some functions on your repository. Is in one of that functions that is slow? Inside Get* are you materializing queries on thousand recors? (Your code seems to be decompiled from an obfuscated exe)